# Visual Basic 2007 Adding values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

To start with I'm not really a wise man. So I was trying to add up two values and display them in a third (that's easy) but I also wanted it to repeat an infinite amount of times (namely that it does the same for every row, let's say I place the result in I5, I want also, on every I under it (I6, I7, I8, etc...)

Should it be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()

if IsNumeric(Range("B1").sort) And IsNumeric(Range("B2").sort) then
Dim value1 As Single
Dim value2 As Single 
range(I5).sort = value+1 + value2

End Sub
```

Or as I think I'm horribly mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `.Sort` property of `Range` where you should be using `.Value`.

There's a couple of ways to achieve what you're looking to do. First option is to iterate through the range and add the relevant value to each cell like so:

```
Public Sub addCells()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

'Set the sheet name
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet_Name")

    'Set the range below:
    Set rng = .Range("I1:I10")

    'Loop through range and add cells together
    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, 2) + cell.Offset(0, 1)
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Another way to do it if the values to be added is ordered in for example column `A` and `B` would be:

```
Public Sub addCells()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

'Set the sheet name
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Add the first formula to the sheet
    .Range("C1").Value = "=SUM(A1+B1)"

    'Change the range below to the range to be filled
    .Range("C1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C1:C10")

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to add in a range, the range should be unlimited. That's where I get the problem.

Still thanks for the help.

Comment: It can't be 'unlimited' as there's a limit to the number of rows / columns in excel. Do you mean you want it to calculate to the last used row?

Comment: Basically. Let me explain further, let's say I want to add A+B and then drop the result in C, I also want to do this an unlimited and random amount of times (Namely, that each row copies the code from the one abode, making the code itself 'unlimited'). Not great at explaining myself, I know.

Comment: So you want to do that for every row in the sheet?

Comment: Yeah mostly. Also I guess the same method would work to make a rule (let's say I want negative values to be in a pink cell, possitives in green and 0 in blue) with changing the adding things to coloration?